# How can I call a bookmarklet from Selenium webdriver in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, bookmarklet

I need to call a Bookmarklet from Selenium WebDriver in JAVA using Eclipse IDE. 
 
 My objective is to 

 1. Load a URL

 2. Call the Bookmarklet

This bookmarklet will generate results from the URL in step 1.

Note : I am newbie in Selenium

Comment: hi, did you tried firefox profile? just do what you required and call that profile by webdriver..

Comment: yeah, I tried FirefoxProfile to get the profile. But clicking on that bookmarklet from that profile is challenging. I am not finding an option to click on it.

Comment: Hi, May i know what is that bookmarklet.. if it contains any web page/URL then you can navigate it to directly from webdriver right? why need to click on that? if it contains javascript, then use javascript execution to do the same..

Comment: Injected the bookmarklet code in ExecuteScript of JavascriptExecutor. It worked as expected.

Comment: good to know as got solution.. you may post that code.. it may helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to click on bookmarklet, tried injecting the javascript into the code using **JavaScriptExecutor**. Below is the sample code of doing the same.

```
 String code= "window.open(\"\",\"dp_debugger\",\"width=800,height=800,location=0,menubar=0,status=0,toolbar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0\").document.write(\"<script language='JavaScript' id=someId src='someJavascriptFile.js'></\"+\"script>\")";
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(code);
    }
```